# How do I create a function that allows me to store all paths to .txt files in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm doing an assignment at school and I am asked to do the following: 
Write a function called get_paths and store it in the Python module utils.py
The function get_paths:
takes one positional parameter called input_folder
the function stores all paths to .txt files in the input_folder in a list
the function returns a list of strings, i.e., each string is a file path

I've tried glob but that only gets me part of the name, I used listdir and got what I wanted but I do not know what to return.

```
def get_path(input_folder):
    for file in os.listdir(input_folder):
        if file.endswith(".txt"):
            print([os.path.join(input_folder, file)])
['C:\\Users\\Maverick.DESKTOP-N0E7K8Q\\Desktop\\python 
notes\\Data\\books\\AnnaKarenina.txt']
['C:\\Users\\Maverick.DESKTOP-N0E7K8Q\\Desktop\\python 
notes\\Data\\books\\HuckFinn.txt']
['C:\\Users\\Maverick.DESKTOP-N0E7K8Q\\Desktop\\python 
notes\\Data\\books\\Macbeth.txt']
```

## the output works but when I move on to the next step, calling the function then creating the variable, I get this

```
final_output = get_paths("../Data/books")
print(final_output)

['../Data/books\\AnnaKarenina.txt']
['../Data/books\\HuckFinn.txt']
['../Data/books\\Macbeth.txt']
None
```

I feel like I needed to return something so that the print function would actually work properly but I don't know what I need to return. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: create a `result = list()` variable, append results to it, return it. Or use a list comprehension

Comment: Your function prints when it should be returning a list of strings according to the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

it seems that you need to return the list of matching filenames.

You can create a list, accumulate into it, and return it:

```
def get_path(input_folder):
    retval = []
    for file in os.listdir(input_folder):
        if file.endswith(".txt"):
            retval.append(os.path.join(input_folder, file))
    return retval
```

or a list comprehension:

```
def get_path(input_folder):
    return [os.path.join(input_folder,file) for file in os.listdir(input_folder) if file.endswith(".txt")]
```

Note that `glob` does exactly that in this case (plus on windows it will also match files ending with `.TXT` (uppercase), when the first solution does not (unless `.lower()` is inserted in the test):

```
import glob, os
def get_path(input_folder):
    return glob.glob(os.path.join(input_folder,"*.txt"))
```

Answer (score 1):

The most memory efficient way to achieve your goal is to convert your function into a generator:

```
def get_path(input_folder):
    for file in os.listdir(input_folder):
        if file.endswith(".txt"):
            yield os.path.join(input_folder, file)
```

And then your list variable can be obtained with a comprehension

```
my_results = [e for e in get_paths("../Data/books")]
```

Print it or use it as needed.

There is no issue with `None` anymore (see comments below). For reference, if it weren't, you could have filtered the comprehension:

```
my_results = [e for e in get_paths("../Data/books") if e is not None]
```

Comment: the None comes from OP original function not returning anything.

Comment: I know right? So I wonder why it does happen. There is an iteration where `file.endswith(".txt")` hits `True` (or it would not return this value) and yet it still returns `None`.. I would need to test more. The filtering does the trick at least. We would need more input from OP

Comment: no it doesn't return None as the function is now tagged as a generator (because of the yield statement). If you don't filter and the directory doesn't contain any txt file, the list will be empty. No need to filter. Try it. Generator/function python magic guesswork in action.

Comment: Ah ok great. I did not understand your first comment then :)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to store your results and return the list, not print it inside the function that explains the `None`

```
def get_path(input_folder):
    result = []
    for file in os.listdir(input_folder):
        if file.endswith(".txt"):
            result.append(os.path.join(input_folder, file))
    return result
```

If you would like to use a comprehension list:

```
def get_path(input_folder):
    return [os.path.join(input_folder, file) for file in os.listdir(input_folder) if file.endswith(".txt")]
```